# How to add rows of a matrix based on an index vector in MATLAB?

Tags: arrays, matlab, matrix, vectorization

If we have two column vector indices and values, we can use `accumarray(indices, values)` to sum repeated values (i.e., entries of the vector values that have matching indices).

Is there an analogous way that works when the vector values becomes a matrix, such that we now sum entire rows instead of scalars?

One way, of course, is to use arrayfun and apply accumarray to each column of the now matrix values individually, which would take the form

```
cell2mat(arrayfun(@(x) accumarray(indices, values(:, x)), 1:size(values, 2), 'UniformOutput', false));
```

Answer (score 4):

### Using `splitapply`

The **[`splitapply`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/splitapply.html)** function is similar to `accumarray` but allows the data to be multidimensional. For example,

```
values = [ 10  20  30
           40  50  60
           70  80  90
          100 110 120
          130 140 150 ];
indices = [2; 1; 2; 3; 1];
result = splitapply(@(x) sum(x,1), values, indices);
```

gives

```
result =
   170   190   210
    80   100   120
   100   110   120
```

A limitation of this approach is that `splitpply`, unlike `accumarray`, requires **the grouping variable not to skip any number**. So for example `indices = [2; 1; 2; 4; 1];` would not be valid.

---

### Using `sparse`

If you want to **allow the grouping variable to skip numbers** you can use [**`sparse`**](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sparse.html), exploiting the fact that this function adds values at matching entries:

```
values = [ 10  20  30
           40  50  60
           70  80  90
          100 110 120
          130 140 150 ];
indices = [2; 1; 2; 4; 1];
result = full(sparse(repmat(indices, 1, size(values,2)),...
                     repmat(1:size(values,2), size(values,1), 1),...
                     values));
```

gives

```
result =
   170   190   210
    80   100   120
     0     0     0
   100   110   120
```

---

### Using matrix multiplication

You can easily build a binary matrix from the grouping variable, such that matrix-multiplying this by the data matrix gives the desired result. This method also **allows skipped numbers**:

```
values = [ 10  20  30
           40  50  60
           70  80  90
          100 110 120
          130 140 150 ];
indices = [2; 1; 2; 4; 1];
result = (indices.'==(1:max(indices)).') * values;
```

again gives

```
result =
   170   190   210
    80   100   120
     0     0     0
   100   110   120
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `accumarray` more effectively:

```
cell2mat(accumarray(indices, 1:size(values, 1), [], @(x){sum(values(x, :), 1)}));
```